# How many handshakes are made by the two teams?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Two ten member basketball teams play a game. After the game, each of the members of the winning team shakes hands once with each member of both teams. How many handshakes take place?

I tried to answer this and I got 145. The two teams will shake 10 × 10 times so 100. the winning team will shake hands 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 45 times.

Is this correct?

Comment: Rather than referring to the handshakes within the winning team as $9+8+7+6+\dots+2+1=45$, it would be quicker and more efficient to describe it as $\binom{10}{2}=45$ instead.  Otherwise, yes, $10^2+\binom{10}{2}=145$ is the answer I would have come up with as well given the phrasing of the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz others answered 190, maybe because they also included the losing team. I don't which is more conventional.

Comment: Quite.  190 assumes that the losing players shook each other's hands, but the problem only says that the *winning* team shook hands within their own team.   The losing players were too mad at each other to interact, but were only polite enough to congratulate the winners

Comment: Note, 190 is (20 choose 2)